# Android - having trouble properly sizing an xml layout used for a listview row

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to set up an xml layout to be used for a row in a `ListView`.  The layout consists of a root `LinearLayout` with a child `RelativeLayout` containing two `ImageViews` (one anchored to the other's bottom/right corner) and a child vertical `LinearLayout` containing two `TextViews`.  I want each row in the listview to have the same width and height, despite the size of the content in the subviews.  I realize I cannot use `wrap_content` which will size the views based on their content, but I'm unclear on what I should use to accomplish a uniform width/height.  I tried using fixed `dp` values, but that just made it even worse.  I've attached two screenshots.  The first one, from the iOS version, shows how it should look, while the second one shows how it looks on the Android version with the following layout.  As a said, I know what's wrong (the `wrap_content` attributes), but how do I change it to size correctly?  Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:id="@+id/campaign_thumbnail_container" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/campaign_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/campaign_mark_new"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@id/campaign_thumbnail"
           android:layout_alignRight="@id/campaign_thumbnail"
           android:src="@drawable/new1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/campaign_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/word_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/campaign_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/campaign_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/campaign_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/campaign_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was about to write an answer similar to @kent-andersen but then I saw the third list entry. It looks like it is only one picture using the full width instead of a picture left and some text right, using half-half of the available space. So, could you please explain what different kinds of list entries exist and how they should be conducted together?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Basically, there are 3 types, 2 of which you see in the screenshot.  A picture on the left with the text on the right, the picture on the right with the text on the left (basically reverse of the first one), and one where there's just the picture and no text.  They must all be the same height and width, despite the size of the pictures (which can vary, they get downloaded), and text.

Comment: Okay. I'm getting closer. And then there's a small indicator, when one list entry is new. This is basically a small square at the bottom, right corner of a bigger square (Therefore the RelativeLayout). Does this small indicator appear at the bottom right of the picture or of the list entry (which would be eventually in the text)?

Comment: It appears at the bottom right of the picture (the first ImageView).

Comment: @kent-anderson has given me an idea though.  Perhaps I could wrap that relativelayout in a linear layout and have weights of .5 for each linearlayout (the one containing the text and the one containing the relative layout with the images).  Hmmm...

Comment: If the indicator is inside of the larger image, you will need a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. LinearLayout always sets the views side-by-side.

Comment: Right, what I mean is, keep the RelativeLayout for that reason, but wrap it inside a Linear Layout.  Then there would be 2 sibling LinearLayouts, one containing the TextViews, and the other containing the RelativeLayout that in turn contains the ImageViews.

Comment: That's what I'm building right now. Check my answer as it growths :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - According to comments below:

One general thing: To size elements in a LinearLayout uniformly, you need to do two things:

- Use a equal `android:layout_weight` for each element
- Make the width or height (whatever has to be uniquely sized) `="0dip"`

This is, because the weight factor is only used to fill the rest of the available space. First all elements are placed using their weight/height, then the still available space is calculated and distributed by weight to each element.

EDIT-end

Now, let me create the layouts step by step. 
First, this would be your layout of one entry without the "new campaign" indication.

```
<!-- Type 1: Picture left, text right. half-half size. Picture resized to fit -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Your Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You get a warning, because the LinearLayout itself has a weight. That is necessary, to give all list entries the same height.

Here's type 2:

```
<!-- Type 2: Picture right, text left. half-half size. Picture resized to fit -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Your Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(Where's my "That was easy!" button?)

And Type 3. Even easier:

```
<!-- Type 3: Picture full width. Picture resized to fit -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

Now the final thing. Put these three layouts in separate XML-files and include them into a wrapping RelativeLayout.

```
<!-- Finally overlay the entry with a new indication -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newIndication"
        android:layout_width="24dip"
        android:layout_height="24dip"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/entry1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/entry1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/type1entry"
        android:id="@+id/entry1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note the `include`. I've put the Type1 LinearLayout in its own XML file named "type1entry". By giving this a new id with `@+id/entry1` I can access this entry explicitely in the Activity. Also, I've given the indicator a size of 24dip in square. Change that to your image accordingly.

I've checked the layouts in Eclipse and they did look as I expected them.

Comment: I will!  It's late here, I need some sleep, but I will later today!

Comment: BTW, another quick question.  Are tabbars in Android typically at the top like I have, as opposed to at the bottom on iOS?

Comment: Yes, tabs are. Actually in Android you have an ActionBar which appear at the top, when there's enough space and expand to the bottom if necessary or automatically add a "more" button. Check the Android developer pagefor [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: Thanks.  This client of mine kind of made a design with iOS in mind, not Android, so I have to try to make them understand that Android's UI is a bit different.

Comment: I tried your approach, and while it gets me quite a bit closer, we're still not quite there yet.  For one thing, I had to modify the xml since there's actually four TextViews rather than one that would take up half the width, so I created a LinearLayout to hold the four TextViews and set the LinearLayout's weight to 1.  It still doesn't seem to be sizing the entries uniformly.  Also I think the scaleType needs to be "fitXY" not "fitCenter" or else the image isn't scaled to full width/weight, and the row appears split between the image and text sections.

Comment: Hey I got it!  The last piece is making sure that the root entry view (the Relative Layout) has a fixed height, so that all the rows will have the same height... thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Cool! About `fitXY`and `fitCenter`: The difference is, that `fitXY` scales x- and y-axis independently, whereas `fitCenter`keeps the aspect ratio.

Comment: Yeah, well they want to fit the image in the whole resized ImageView, so fitXY is the way to go.  Also, I resorted to dynamically setting the height of the rows in the code based on how many rows I wanted to show in the viewable area without scrolling.  But other than it, it's golden... cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use a relative layout?
If not, use linearLayout with weights like this.

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:id="@+id/campaign_thumbnail_container"
       android:weightSum="100" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/campaign_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/campaign_mark_new"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:src="@drawable/new1"
           android:layout_weight=50
           android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

This is untested, but similar solutions like this have worked for me in the past.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I must use the relative layout, as the second image is actually flush against the bottom right of the first image.  Sorry, you don't see in the screenshot because in some cases it's hidden.  It's a small image to indicate it's a new entry.  Note the following in @+id/campaign_mark_new : android:layout_alignBottom="@id/campaign_thumbnail"
           android:layout_alignRight="@id/campaign_thumbnail"